# passing newline (\n) from excel to variable Protractor

Tags: excel, selenium, protractor

I am reading data from excel for assertion.

I pass following text in excel

```
"Urgent Care | New Patient Intake – Pre-Visit\n\nInpatient Care"
```

(has 2 new lines) but when the value is extracted from excel and stored in variable it is saved as following -

```
"Urgent Care | New Patient Intake – Pre-Visit\\\n\\\nInpatient Care"
```

Error :

```
AssertionError: expected 'Urgent Care | New Patient Intake – Pre-Visit\n\nInpatient Care' to include 'Urgent Care | New Patient Intake – Pre-Visit\\n\\nInpatient Care'
```

How do I pass `\n` from excel to variable without having extra `\`

Comment: how did you store value in excel?

Comment: manually i have stored the value in excel.

Comment: I mean how ? like with \n?